# Kendo-Knockout TreeView selected is undefined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui, treeview

I'm trying to remove selected item, but it always undefined.

ViewModel:

```
     var inline = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        data: data.layers,
        schema: {
            model: {
                children: "layers"
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(inline.data().toJSON())
    var viewModel = {
        treeViewDataSource: ko.observable(inline),
        onSelect: function(e) {
            console.log(viewModel.isSelected())
            e.preventDefault();
            $(that).trigger("treewasclicked", {
                data: $('#avaliableLayersul').data('kendoTreeView').dataItem(e.node)
            });

        },
        isSelected: ko.observable()
    };
```

And there is View.Also I create context(treeLayersVMVV is class from main model, that include treeView model)

```
<div id='avaliableLayers' data-bind="with: treeLayersVMVV">
        <ul id='avaliableLayersul' data-bind="kendoTreeView: {dataSource:treeViewDataSource,dataValueField:'options.id', dataTextField:'options.displayName',selectable: true , selected: isSelected , select: onSelect, checkboxes: {checkChildren: true}  }"></ul>
</div>
```

So, firstly, when I click on element, it does not become orange. Element has only lightgrey border. As I get idea, it means that element is not selected, but in DOM tree clicked element is active.
How to fix it? Google didn't show anithing....

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,

onSelect:  e.preventDefault();
...
But still, selected is undefined